# EXC_GUARD exception

Tags: macos, exception

A OSX app crashes when I try to close a socket handle, it worked fine in all the previous platforms, but it appears to crash in Yosemite.

The line where is crashes is

```
-(void)stopPacketReceiver
{
   close(sd);
}
```

In Xcode it pauses all the threads and show EXC_GUARD exception, what kind of exception is this, any ideas ?

Thanks,
Ahmed

EDIT:

Here r the exception codes that I get

Exception Type:        EXC_GUARD
Exception Codes:       0x4000000100000000, 0x08fd4dbfade2dead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a [post in Apple's old developer forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/915209#915209) from Quinn "The Eskimo" (Apple Developer Relations, Developer Technical Support, Core OS/Hardware), edited by me to remove things which were specific to that specific case:

> EXC_GUARD is a change in 10.9 designed to help you detect file
>   descriptor problems.  Specifically, the system can now flag specific
>   file descriptors as being guarded, after which normal operations on
>   those descriptors will trigger an EXC_GUARD crash (when it wants to
>   operate on these file descriptors, the system uses special 'guarded'
>   private APIs).
>
> We added this to the system because we found a lot of apps were
>   crashing mysteriously after accidentally closing a file descriptor
>   that had been opened by a system library.  For example, if an app
>   closes the file descriptor used to access the SQLite file backing a
>   Core Data store, Core Data would then crash mysteriously much later
>   on.  The guard exception gets these problems noticed sooner, and thus
>   makes them easier to debug.
>
> For an EXC_GUARD crash, the exception codes break down as follows:
>
> o The first exception code … contains three bit
>   fields:
>
> - The top three bits … indicate [the type of guard].
> - The remainder of the top 32 bits … indicate [which operation was disallowed].
> - The bottom 32 bits indicate the descriptor in question ….
>
> o The second exception code is a magic number associated with the
>   guard.  …

Your code is closing a socket it doesn't own. Maybe `sd` contains the descriptor number for a descriptor that you once owned but is now a dangling reference, because you already closed your descriptor and that number has now been reused for somebody else's descriptor. Or maybe `sd` just has a junk value somehow.

We can decode some more information from the exception codes, but most likely you just have to trace exactly where you're doing with `sd` over its life.

---

Update:

From the edited question, I see that you've posted the exception codes. Using the constants from the [kernel source](http://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2782.20.48/bsd/sys/guarded.h), the type of guard is `GUARD_TYPE_FD`, the operation that was disallowed was `kGUARD_EXC_CLOSE` (i.e. `close()`), and the descriptor was 0 (FILENO_STDIN).

So, in all probability, your `stopPacketReceiver` was called when the `sd` instance variable was uninitialized and had the default 0 value that all instance variables get when an object is first allocated.

The magic value is `0x08fd4dbfade2dead`, which according to the original developer forums post, "indicates that the guard was applied by SQLite". That seems strange. Descriptor 0 would normally be open from process launch (perhaps referencing /dev/null). So, SQLite should not own that.

I suspect what has happened is that your code has actually closed descriptor 0 twice. The first time it was not guarded. It's legal to close `FILENO_STDIN`. Programs sometimes do it to reopen that descriptor to reference something else (such as /dev/null) if they don't want/need the original standard input. In your case, it would have been an accident but would not have raised an exception. Once it was closed, the descriptor would have been available to be reallocated to the next thing which opened a descriptor. I guess that was SQLite. At that time, SQLite put a guard on the descriptor. Then, your code tried to close it again and got the `EXC_GUARD` exception.

If I'm right, then it's somewhat random that your code got the exception (although it was always doing something bad). The fact that file descriptor 0 got assigned to a subsystem that applied a guard to it could be a race condition or it could be a change in order of operations between versions of the OS.

You need to be more careful to not close descriptors that you didn't open. You should initialize any instance variable meant to hold a file descriptor to -1, not 0. Likewise, if you close a descriptor that you did own, you should set the instance variable back to -1.

Comment: Thanks for the info Ken, I have added the exception codes above, can you help me further identify what those codes r saying. Also I want to know I have a C library dylib which this app uses, any socket handles created in that library are still part of my process or no ?. You mentioned that your code is closing a socket it doesn't own, I believed that socket handles are unique within a process but not unique within the system ? so how would it be possible for my application to close a socket it does not own ? I might have wrong assumptions so please I Will appreciate if you can shed some light

Comment: I have edited my answer to explain the exception codes. Any sockets created by a library in your process are part of your process, yes. Your *process* does own the file descriptor but your *code* does not. The file descriptor was opened by system frameworks and is owned by those frameworks. You are not entitled to close it. That's what the guard was created to enforce.

Comment: Right, so even if it was a function call of my process which calls some system framework and then that framework somehow declares that descriptor to be guarded. correct ?

Comment: BTW I have got it fixed, by properly initialising the variable with -1 after close is called on it and by ensuring it is initialised with -1 right at the very start as well.. Please do address my above comment thanks :)

Comment: Yes, your process called into a system framework. That system framework opened a file descriptor for its own internal use and set it to be guarded (using Apple-private means). Your code closed that descriptor, triggering the guard. You're welcome.

Comment: @kenthomases, I also encountered similar crash, and I was wonder if there's a way you can programmatically identify if the file descriptor you're about to close, is in fact guarded ? thanks

Comment: @Zohar81, not to my knowledge. That shouldn't be needed, though. Your code should never be closing descriptors that you're not sure you own.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, that sounds awesome - it *sounds like* it caught what would have been EXC_BAD_ACCESS (but this is a guess).

My guess is that `sd` isn't a valid descriptor. It's possible an API changed in Yosemite that's causing the place you create the descriptor to return NULL, or it's possible a change in the event timeline in Yosemite causes it to have already been cleaned up.

Debugging tip here: trace back `sd` all the way to its creation.

Comment: interesting thing is it does not complain and just silently goes when close on sd is called even before socket is created.. I am still trying to work it out